# Lagging instead of executing a tkinter for-loop using arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to animate a "round" explosion with the colors in `colors` but whenever I run it, it freezes and does nothing.

Thank you!

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *
from time import *
from math import *

space = Tk()
s = Canvas(space, height = 1000, width = 1000, background = "light blue")
s.pack()


##EXPLOSION

xE = 375
yE = 475

x = []
y = []
r = []

rSpd = []

eAngle = []

xAr = []
yAr = []

colors = []
drawing = []
sleep(1)
cakeE = 500
colors = ["#EA7FF0","#E44FEE","#87078F","#F9DBFB","#F7B8FB","gray76","grey","white"]
for i in range( cakeE ):                                       
    x.append( xE )
    y.append( yE )

    xAr.append( randint(1, 3) )
    yAr.append( randint(1, 3) )

    r.append( 0 )
    rSpd.append(0)

    eAngle.append( uniform(1,15) )
    eAngle.append( uniform(0, 2*pi) )

    drawing.append(0)
    colors.append( choice(colors) )
for f in range(400):                                                 

    for i in range(cakeE):

        drawing[i] = s.create_rectangle( x[i], y[i], x[i] + xAr[i], y[i]\
                                         + yAr[i], fill = colors[i] )

        x[i] = xE + r[i] * cos( eAngle[i] )
        y[i] = yE - r[i] * sin( eAngle[i] )

        r[i] = r[i] + rSpd[i]
        eAngle[i] = eAngle[i]+0.01
```

Comment: You've posted way too much code. Please try to reduce it down to a [mcve].

Comment: Please scale this down to a [minimal, complete, and verifiablee example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This is probably caused by `sleep()`. In tkinter you do not want to use sleep as it will cause the application to freeze. Instead incorporate `after()`

Comment: @Mike-SMT "NameError: name 'after' is not defined". How would you go about doing that?

Comment: Look up the use of `after()` in tkinter. You need to specify something to "track" the time. for example you can use the root window of `space` and you will need to provide a function to call after the time is up. `space.after(1000, some_func_name)`. Keep in mind 1000 = 1 sec.

Answer (score 0):

With the code you have provided (not a MCVE) its hard to help with the matter.
However here is an example use of `after()` to show you how it is used. This example should be enough for you to replace `sleep()` with `after()` keep in mind you will likely need to move some of your code into a function for this to work correctly.

```
from tkinter import *


space = Tk()
lbl = Label(space, text="Before timed event.")
lbl.pack()

def do_something():
    global lbl
    lbl.config(text="After timed event.")
    # execute some code here

# set a 3 second timer to activate the do something function.       
space.after(3000, do_something)

space.mainloop()
```